# При focus() каретка в Mozilla Firefox встаёт в самое начало

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chrome и Opera (всё нормально):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Mozilla Firefox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/k9ay7fk8/1/

```js
$('#test_button_focus').click(function() {
  $('#test').val($('#test').val());
  $('#test').focus();

  // просто $('#test').focus() ставит каретку в самом начале во всех браузерах
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test" value="test" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="test_button_focus" value="test focus" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вариант могу предложить:

Сначала делаете фокус, потом сбрасываете значение, и обратно ставите.

```js
$('#test_button_focus').click(function() {

  $('#test').focus();

  var value = $('#test').val();
  $('#test').val('');
  $('#test').val(value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="test" />
<br /> 
<br />
<input type="button" id="test_button_focus" value="test focus" />
```

Comment: отличный вариант. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вариант установки курсора в конец текста

```js
$("#test_button_focus").click(function() {
  var elem = $("#test")[0],
    val = elem.value,
    pos = val.length;
  elem.value = val;
  elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
  elem.focus()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="test" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="test_button_focus" value="test focus" />
```